# CMake and MinGW-w64 include paths

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw-w64

I have a C++ project that needs to be built with CMake and MinGW-W64.

Some libraries (such as zlib, libpng) are in: `C:\Dev\mingw64-5.3.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32\`

So I use : `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Dev\mingw64-5.3.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32"`

But, I get a compilation error because the following header is outdated and miss important symbols:

```
C:\Dev\mingw64-5.3.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\float.h
```

If I add a compiler flag to search into the proper include directory for float.h:

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-isystem C:/Dev/mingw64-5.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/include"
```

Then, this does not work, since CMake will add this folder after its generated includes_CXX.rsp

How can I handle this issue? Is there a way to enforce header search path priority?

Comment: You may want to upgrade your compiler rather that juggle system includes. The latter is unsustainable.

Comment: OK, just switched to the latest MinGW (8.1.0) and the result is the same.

Comment: Please show the errors you are getting. I don't understand why you are adding the system include path to the compiler flags, it is already your system include path by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add the `include` location(s) to environment variable `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`.

To locate the libraries you can do the same for the `lib` with the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

For DLL and EXE files you may even need to add the `bin` path to `PATH`.